# I'm stuck on a question Calculus:Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{e^x (x^4 + 4)}{(x^2+1)^{5/2}} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

I have tried a lot of methods but none is able to simplify the expression, it keep s getting more complex and harder to solve, I would be glad if someone would be willing to give me a kickstart, Thanks

I tried to simplify the expression into elementary form by opening the brackets and multiplying but nothing simplified, can a substitution be done to simplify?

P.S. This is not for homework I am a 12th-grade kid and I am learning calculus on my own, I was stuck on this question I found online.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  Please write in MathJax for readability.

Comment: thanks for the edit GNU supporter, I didn't know how to write like that

Comment: ithink there is no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960)
and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site.
In particular, [people will be more willing to help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I don't think that's a usual high school HW question since the usual substitution $x = \tan t$ for denominator would give $e^{\tan t}$ in the integrand.

Comment: @GNUSupporter He said this isn't homework...

Comment: It doesn't look like there is an elementary solution to this problem. Where did you see this online? You could see this as an opportunity to learn approximation techniques, or just ignore it and move on.

Comment: well not exactly online, I was going through some book PDF(s) of my brother's calculus book collection and in there I found this question

Comment: @Théophile Yes you're right, as can be seen from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex+*+(x%5E4%2B4)+%2F+(x%5E2%2B1)%5E(5%2F2))

Comment: @Théophile what is exactly this approximation technique? isn't it for definite integration this is indefinite integration

Comment: Was this an indefinite integral? Or perhaps it was a definite integral?

Comment: @Clayton it's indefinite

Comment: By Risch algorithm the primitive is non-elementary. What is the origin of such problem? I do not see any purpose in asking to compute non-elementary integrals like this one or $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: I checked and this question is from a preparatory book for IITJEE

Comment: @SkV Name of the book ?

Comment: @user45914123 Register 1 by AKJ

Comment: @SkV Sorry I can't find the book on Amazon. Can you give a link to it ?

Comment: @user45914123 No link can be given to it, it is not commercially available

Comment: @user45914123 It was written by Abhijit Kumar Jha(my high school math teacher & my brother's too) he used to maintain a blog, here is the link https://akj259.wordpress.com/, I have the PDF but I am not allowed to share it for obvious reasons

Comment: @SkV Oh, ok. Did you ask your teacher how to do this problem ?

Comment: No, not yet, I will add a solution here when he tells me the solution.

Comment: @SkV Looking forward to it. I must your high school math teacher is too good for a high school teacher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72239/discussion-between-skv-and-user45914123).

Answer (score 0):

I may contribute here.. This may be more simpler ..

We can substitute $x = \tan(t), \implies dx = \sec^{2}(t) dt $ and get 
$$ \int \frac{e^{\tan(t)}(\tan^{4}(t) + 4)}{(\tan^{2}(t) + 1)^{5/2}}dx = \int \frac{e^{\tan(t)}(\tan^{4}(t) + 4)}{(\sec^{2}(t))^{5/2}} \sec^{2}(t) dt $$
$$ = \int \frac{e^{\tan(t)}(\tan^{4}(t) + 4)}{\sec^{3}(t)} dt $$

Now remember that

> $$ e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}  $$

so we have

> $$ e^{\tan(t)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{n}(t)}{n!}  $$

Using this for the integral, we calculate instead :

$$ \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{n}(t)}{n!}  \frac{(\tan^{4}(t) + 4)}{\sec^{3}(t)} dt $$
$$ = \int \cos^{3}(t) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{n+4}(t) + 4 \tan^{n}(t)}{n!}   dt   $$
$$ =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left[ \int \cos^{3}(t) \left( \tan^{n+4}(t) + 4 \tan^{n}(t) \right)   dt \right]  $$

I think this may be simpler, but I have not found full solution. Maybe it can be solved *directly*, or maybe using *induction*. Hope this helps.