# a problem that I'm stuck on in Calculus:Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left[\int\cos^3t\left(\tan^{n+4}(t)+4\tan^n(t)\right)\,\mathrm dt\right]$$

This is the integral that I want to calculate any ways that you can suggest so as it becomes easier to solve
If you are wondering the source of the question then it's actually part of a bigger problem, which was the integration of $$\int \frac{e^x (x^4 + 4)}{(x^2+1)^{5/2}} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
[StackExchange's Solution to the First Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612541/im-stuck-on-a-question-calculusintegration)

Comment: If the question has an issue please bring it to my notice, instead of down-voting, I will fix it as fast as I can

Comment: Please type your question (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok I will try

Comment: I will be really grateful to anyone who can write the question in MathJax.

Comment: Linking [the first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612541/im-stuck-on-a-question-calculusintegration) question.

Comment: @SkV Done. What do you think?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, I promise I will learn MathJax and use it the next time, any tips from the pro?

Comment: @SkV If I had one, I would have already provided it.

Comment: Regarding mathjax, if you see some other place where someone has used a similar expression to the one you want to use, right click on it, and you will get an option to see how to write it in mathjax.  It is a good way to learn it.  As for your problem.  It doesn't look like it is going to integrate into any functions that you are going to be able to understand.  You might as well define the "SkV" function to be that integral.

Comment: I have had a look at your previous question and the kind of deadend you are embarked into now because of a pseudo-answer...  I would be you, I would consider starting back from the initial integral.

Comment: @JeanMarie Starting back is an option but I'm skeptical to if I would be able to solve this integral, I have tried a lot but the integral doesn't simplify, my knowledge of calculus is very scarce relative to others in the stack community as I'm in high school right now.

Comment: I insist on the fact that the direction that has been indicated to you most surely doesn't help.