# Can this be integrated?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{e^x}{(x^2+1)^{5/2}} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

Can the function be integrated, this question is linked to 2 more questions that I asked, they were not answered, I about to solve if I am able to solve this integral, I checked [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7Bx%7D%7D%7B%20%5Cleft(1%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7Ddx) & [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(e%5Ex)%2F((1%2Bx%5E2)%5E(5%2F2))+dx), but no solution could be found

Please just answer that can the integral be solved using moderate-level calculus, with a hint, no need to provide a solution.

[Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618029/a-problem-that-im-stuck-on-in-calculusintegration?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612541/im-stuck-on-a-question-calculusintegration?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If the question has an issue please bring it to my notice, instead of down-voting, I will fix it as fast as I can

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking to write the x^4+4 in the main question as x^4+2 + 2 so as I am able to integrate x^4+2, I am trying to integrate the latter

Comment: Letting $x=\tan\theta$ so that $dx = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta$ and $x^2+1 = sec^2\theta,$ we have $$ \int \frac{e^x}{(x^2+1)^{5/2}} \, dx = \int\frac{e^{\tan\theta}}{\sec^5 \theta} \, \sec^2\theta\, d\theta = \int e^{\tan\theta} \cos^3\theta\, d\theta.$$ I'm not sure whether integrating by parts gets you anywhere after that.

Comment: The Risch algorithm proves that your function does not have an elementary antiderivative, which is not surprising.

Comment: And [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) is a Wikipedia article on the Risch Algorithm.